# How do i fix terraform invalid JSON policy

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, aws-eks

I am trying to use a file which contains load balancer iam policy for my AWS in terraform. However when i run the terraform script, i get an error stating:

```
 Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON policy
│ 
│   with module.iam.aws_iam_policy.test-AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy,
│   on ../resources/IAM/main.tf line 77, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "test-AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy":
│   77:  policy = jsonencode(var.policy_file)
```

I am importing the content of the policy file with jsonencode function.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "test-AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy" {
 name = var.aws_loadbalancer_controller_policy
 policy = jsonencode(var.policy_file)
}
```

the value of the iam_policy_file variable above is passed in like `file("../resources/IAM/policy.json")` and the content of that file is shown below, i have checked to see if this json file parses online as a valid json and it does, however Terraform throws the error as if there it is badly formatted.

**policy.json**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:GetCoipPoolUsage",
                "ec2:DescribeCoipPools",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "acm:DescribeCertificate",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
                "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
                "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACLForResource",
                "wafv2:AssociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:DisassociateWebACL",
                "shield:GetSubscriptionState",
                "shield:DescribeProtection",
                "shield:CreateProtection",
                "shield:DeleteProtection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateSecurityGroup"
                },
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/app/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/net/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebAcl",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I downloaded this file from the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html)

I have also tried to make it work by reading in the file from an http response as shown below and i still get the same issue of **Invalid JSON**

```
data "http" "policy_json" {
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4.4/docs/install/iam_policy.json"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "test-AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy" {
  name = var.aws_loadbalancer_controller_policy
  policy = data.http.policy_json.request_body
}
```

Comment: surely not *request* body, you mean [`.response_body`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http#response_body) right?

Comment: While in your initial attempt: `jsonencode(var.policy_file)`. I would assume the filename in itself isn't a valid json, should have tried to `data "local_file"` from that variable, then jsonencode the output of that data, as suggested by your error. Otherwise, @mdaniel suggestion might help as well

Comment: I specifically didn't dig into that part of the question, but AIUI `jsonencode(legal_json_str)` is going to emit _double encoded_ JSON, but the bogus http version was easy to spot. I've never gotten `terraform console` to do anything for me in order to quickly test that theory, though

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that you are assigning a string containing a JSON representation of an object.

It's hard to follow exactly how you have this set up from your description, but here are some potential problems you should check for:

1. If `var.policy_file` contains a filename, then JSON encoding that filename will produce a JSON string containing the filename. For example, if `var.policy_file` is `../resources/IAM/policy.json` then JSON encoding that will produce literally `"../resources/IAM/policy.json"`, which is not a valid IAM policy.
2. If `var.policy_file` contains the direct result of `file("../resources/IAM/policy.json")` then you are asking Terraform to create a JSON encoding of a string that already contains JSON content. For example, if your file contains `{"Version": "2012-10-17"}` then JSON encoding this will produce `"{\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\"}"` -- a JSON string which happens to contain more JSON, which is also not a valid IAM policy.

In both of the situations above you would not need to use `jsonencode` at all, because this file presumably already contains JSON content.

For case 1, you can say `policy = file(var.policy_file)` to directly assign the contents of the file.

For case 2, you can say `policy = var.policy_file` to directly assign the JSON string that's in that variable.

You only need to use `jsonencode` if you are intending to assign a Terraform object value that has not *already* been JSON encoded, like this:

```
policy = jsonencode({
  "Version" = "2012-10-17"
  # ...
})
```

In that case, `jsonencode` is needed to transform the non-string Terraform object value into a JSON string that the `policy` argument is expecting.

Comment: You're right. My original file is a .json, so I don't need to `jsonencode`